# ForEach Controller won't run multiple HTTP Requests

Tags: jmeter

I have a ForEach Controller that loops over an array of values which works. Inside the ForEach block I have two HTTP requests and one extractor.

```
ForEach Loop {
  + HTTP Request 1 (This uses attribute from ForEach)
      +  Extractor
  + HTTP Request 2 (This uses attribute from Extractor)
}
```

The first HTTP request runs and the extractor as well but the second HTTP request fails to run.

I've checked the logs and nothing is mentioned about this HTTP Request. I also tried moving the Extractor out from under the HTTP Requestor 1 but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to have multiple [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) as ForEach Controller children

[image]

The possible reasons for not executing the 2nd HTTP Request are in:

1. Your extractor fails somewhere somehow, double check that the variable is set and has expected value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)
2. Your 2nd HTTP Request configuration is not correct, i.e. invalid characters in "Server Name" field or unsupported protocol or the request is actually being executed but takes too long, etc. I would recommend looking into [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) as normally it has enough troubleshooting information